# Java Merge Two Sorted Lists cause memory limit exceeded. What's the difference between my and one of the right one?

Tags: java, merge, linked-list, sortedlist

This is my wrong answer. I tried to merge the `l2` to `l1`. I first make two listnode to reference the `l1` and `l2`. The manipulate with `t1` and `t2`.

```
public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
 //find the smallest num to be first
    if(l1 == null || l2 == null)
       return l1==null? l2:l1;
   //make t1.val < t2.val
   ListNode t1 = l1.val < l2.val ? l1 :l2;
   ListNode t2 = l1.val > l2.val ? l1 :l2;
   ListNode head = t1;
   while(t1.next != null && t2 !=null){
       if(t2.val < t1.next.val){
           ListNode p2 = t2;
           t2 = t2.next;
           p2.next = t1.next;
           t1.next = p2;
        } 
        else 
          t1 = t1.next;
   }
   t1.next = t2;
   return head;
}
```

This is one of the right answer, What's the difference?

```
public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    if(l1==null || l2==null) return l1==null? l2 : l1;
    ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
    dummy.next = l1;
    ListNode p1 = dummy;
    ListNode p2 = l2; 

    while(p1.next!=null && p2!=null){
        if(p2.val<p1.next.val){
            ListNode t = p2;
            p2 = p2.next;
            t.next = p1.next;
            p1.next = t;
        }
        p1 = p1.next;
    }
    if(p1.next == null && p2!=null) p1.next = p2;
    return dummy.next;
}
```

Comment: `This is my wrong answer` - you get wrong answer or memory limit exceeded? If you get the later, are you getting it evreytime?

Comment: What is `ListNode`? Is it your own list implementation? Java already has list implementations - `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 2):

OutOfMemoryError occurs when your program occupies memory without un-referencing it, thus leaving no chance to the Garbage Collector to free it. In a matter of little time, no memory remains available for the JVM and then it cannot continue executing the program, and then throws this error.

The difference beteen your program and the "good" alternative is that the latter uses a temporary collection to store the result. Your program, instead, stores the results in one of the very input collections. So, if in each iteration you are adding items to the same collection from which you are reading, the reading will never end. That's why it's safer to use a different collection to store the results.

Comment: The "correct" solution does not use a temporary collection, only a single extra dummy node. The algorithms in the two versions are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really getting memory limit exceeded? I don't see how that's possible, you don't allocate any memory.

There are a few errors though. For example, what if l1.val == l2.val? Both t1 and t2 will point to l2.

```
ListNode t1 = l1.val < l2.val ? l1 :l2; 
ListNode t2 = l1.val > l2.val ? l1 :l2;
```

Try running the code with random lists, that may uncover further problems in it.